# std::unordered_map strange behavior

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I'm having some trouble creating a minimal reproducible code snippet for this question. The issue seems to be complex and involves several dependencies and components that are difficult to isolate. I apologize for the inconvenience caused, and I'll do my best to describe the problem thoroughly.

I was solving a `Leetcode` [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/smallest-sufficient-team/description/). I noticed a strange behavior in my code given below.

```cpp
std::vector<int> smallestSufficientTeam(std::vector<std::string>& reqSkills, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& people) {
   const int TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS = reqSkills.size();
   const int TOTAL_PEOPLE = people.size();
   const int REQ_SKILLS_BIT_MAP = (1 << TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS) - 1;
   std::unordered_map<std::string, int> bitIndex;
   for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS; ++i) {
       bitIndex[reqSkills[i]] = i;
   }
   std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> teams = { { 0, {} } };
   teams.reserve(1  << TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS);
   for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_PEOPLE; ++i) {
       int currPersonSkills = 0;
       for (const std::string& skill : people[i]) {
               currPersonSkills |= (1 << bitIndex[skill]);
       }
       for (const auto& [teamSkills, teamIndexes] : teams) {
           const int newTeamSkills = teamSkills | currPersonSkills;
           const auto it = teams.find(newTeamSkills);
           if (it == teams.end() || it->second.size() > 1 + teamIndexes.size()) {
               teams[newTeamSkills] = teamIndexes;
               teams[newTeamSkills].push_back(i);
           }
       }
   }
   return teams[REQ_SKILLS_BIT_MAP];
}
```

**CASES:**

- On removing the line `teams.reserve(1 << TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS);`, I'm
  getting the wrong answer in one of the sample test cases (Sample Test
  Case 2). **But how can not-reserving the space lead to the wrong
  answer?**
- On changing the line `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> teams = { { 0, {} } };` to `unordered_map<int, vector<int>> teams; teams[0] = {};`, the code works fine irrespective of reserving the space. But I think (may be wrong) both the line should be producing the same behavior in the given code.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: It seems like you try to modify `teams` in the ranged for-loop. If so, that doesn't work, as the loop will cache `begin` and `end` iterators.

Comment: @AshutoshAswal Not sure how you assume you did this. `if (it == teams.end() || ...)` can execute the consequence, if the element is not found in the map resuling in `teams[newTeamSkills]` inserting a new mapping into your map. If this happens further use of any preexisting iterators on the `teams` object becomes undefined behaviour. The ranged for loop ***is*** using such iterators.

Comment: Side notes : `const int TOTAL_REQ_SKILLS = reqSkills.size();`. Don't use int to store sizes, C++ has `std::size_t` for that. It is also not necessary at all to store this locally, just use `reqSkills.size()` the compiler is smart enough to see you use it in more then one place and store it in some register if it can (it is an invariant in the scope).

Comment: questions should be self contained and not rely on external links

Comment: If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated.

Comment: *“But how can not-reserving the space lead to the wrong answer?”* Let me guess: Dangling iterators or dangling pointers combined with reallocation (which is less likely to occur when you `.reserve()`)?

Comment: The bug is here: `teams[newTeamSkills] = teamIndexes;` ← This invalidates **all** iterators into `teams` (in general, by API definition, not _always_), because it may cause a reallocation of underlying data structures. This is why `.reserve()` “helps”, but in case of a hash map you can _never_ be sure. What to do instead: Put newly added `newTeamSkills` in a new, independent hash map and then, **after** the loop (once you no longer hold iterators into `teams`), merge the new map into `teams`. A range-based `for` loop is syntax sugar around `.begin()` and `.end()` and uses iterators internally.

Comment: BTW, I bet that `valgrind` would have told you about the problem; it would most likely show you that you have use-after-free errors somewhere in the `teams` map loop. This is because the `for` loop holds iterators pointing into the map during the time the map may reallocate its internal storage. In a range-based `for`-loop, read-only access is OK, writing map _values_ arbitrarily is OK, but additions / removals of map _keys_ (i.e. changes to the map structure itself) are **not** OK.